# Is asking for review of 3rd party code ok?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-policy, asking-questions, third-party

Most code people are posting here seems to be code they have written themselves. In [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35115/php-compare-3-session-management-scripts) the OP asked basically for a review of three 3rd party scripts.

I'm not sure that this question is a good fit as it stands but as alternative he could ask three questions asking one for each script to be reviewed.

Assuming he includes the source (including licensing attributions) would that be in the spririt of CR?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [What topics I can ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer must be yes to all questions:
>
> 1. Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
> 2. Did I write that code?
> 3. Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> 4. Do I want the code to be good code, (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> 5. To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
> 6. Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
>
> If you answered yes to all the above questions, your question is
>   on-topic for Code Review.

Third party code would fail number 2.

I think it also is **against the spirit** of Code Review.  If the asker can't understand the code in the first place then they won't be able to understand the review of the code.  The question is just asking for a product selection to be made for free.

Comment: I think this number 2 isn't stressed enough. There recently was another post where an employer was aking for a review of one of his employee's code (and then decide if that person would remain employed). The Help Center should make it clear that it's off-topic and *against the spirit* to post *someone else's code* for review.

Answer (score 6):

I think the accepted answer needs an update because now the faq states

*** Am I an owner or maintainer of the code?**

If you are going to be maintaining the 3rd party code going forward, then yes this it the right site for you. (I love this change)

Comment: Then you are free to update that answer.  It doesn't appear that making that change will invalidate the later part of the answer.

Comment: I think you're still expected to _understand_ the code (asking for explanation is off-topic, but asking for improvements is welcome).